# ¿Comó configurar el archivo host en Centos para que que redirija a localhost con una url determinada?

Tags: centos, host

Saludos estoy tratando de configurar el archivo **hosts** en CentOS 7 para esto mediante la consola digito:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

en dicho archivo archivo agrego:

```
http://test.example.com/   localhost:8000
```

la idea es que al digitar "**test.example.com**" me redirija a **localhost:8000** este es un proyecto de **Django**.

una vez grabados los cambios realizo el siguiente comando para que surjan los cambios:

```
systemctl restart systemd-hostnamed
```

Pero a pesar de todos estos cambios no he logrado que redirija a localhost , quiza alguna sugerencia gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evita usar localhost y asignar primero la dirección a la cual va a ser redirigido por el enlace, por cierto no puedes asignar los puertos, solo la dirección ip

```
127.0.0.1 test.example.com
```